# Not able to run firebase stripe/firestore-stripe-payments extension in emulator locally for a web application

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-admin, firebase-tools, firebase-extensions

I tried to install **Run Payments with Stripe** extension (https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) from firebase for the project **mySampleProject** in my local emulator, but it's not showing in the emulator list.

I tried the following commands from cloud functions folder from my workspace:

1. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. `firebase ext:install stripe/firestore-stripe-payments --local --project=mySampleProject`

(i tried with `firebase ext:install stripe/firestore-stripe-payments@0.3.1 --local --project=mySampleProject` also)

3. `firebase emulators:start`

I could see the extension name is added in firebase.json file :
[image]

But, the extension is not showing up on emulator dashboard & error is displayed in the emulator log :
[image]
[image]

To resolve this issue , i ran **npm install** in my local folder, updated the firebase-admin version to latest **11.1.0** , still no luck .

Below are the dependecies in my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.17.0",
    "@slack/web-api": "^6.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "condense-whitespace": "^2.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.17.0",
    "firebase-admin": "11.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.20.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "scrape-it": "^5.3.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.16"
   }
```

My node version : **16.17.0** (I tried downgrading the node version also to fix the issue)

Can anyone help me in fixing the issue ??? Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I updated the firebase tools and started working. I think it was a Firebase issue and they fixed it.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```